# Can you exit the Deep Woods without growing a beanstalk?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

In the Steam Gardens (Wooded Kingdom), falling in certain places causes you to land in the Deep Woods. While you can find a seed to grow a beanstalk, this takes a while, and you have to do this every time you fall. I'm also aware that you can exit with a save and reload, but this requires restarting the game. Is there any way to fast travel out of the Deep Woods back to the surface?

Comment: Why can't you just fast-travel to any checkpoint or the Odyssey?

Comment: I think fast travel is disabled when in the deep woods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The only ways to exit the Deep Woods are climbing the beanstalk or reloading a save. Fast travelling is disabled in the Deep Woods.**

This information is mentioned on the [Super Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Deep_Woods)

> The only possible escape from the area (without saving and quitting) is to plant a seed granted to Mario by a Steam Gardener into one of four pots in the area and climb a beanstalk back to the kingdom's mainland.

I've also watched a few Super Mario Odyssey speedrunners do challenge runs. Usually when they fall into Deep Woods, if they don't reset the run, they exit by growing and climbing the beanstalk. For example, below is a video of speedrunner cjay using the beanstalk during a 1 finger challenge.